# Detecting multihomed machine

Tags: linux, networking, solaris, ip, networkcard

Is there a way to reliably detect whether or not a machine is multi-homed? I'd like to be able to write a script that will return a true or false regarding that information.

Comment: How are you defining multi-homed?  Multiple up-stream links, multiple network interfaces, multiple IP addresses?  Having ip_forwarding enabled?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming#Multihoming_variants

Comment: Ideally, all of those situations should be detected, though I don't need to identify which one is present. I realize this may not be a trivial task, but I'm researching my options at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate the definition of a multihomed machine as one having two default routes. A more precise definition would require determining how independent the routes are, which does seem daunting.

```
route -n | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0" {++r} END {exit(r<2)}'
route -n --inet6 | awl '$1 == "::/0" {++r} END {exit(r<2)}'
```

(The Solaris calls may require tweaking.)